# Images not downloading on second load in WPF

Tags: wpf, http, azure

I have a WPF application which has a `UserControl` called MyBook that, on Loaded will fire a background thread to get a list of Domain Objects each with a URL to an Azure Image hosted in blob storage.

For each domain object I get back, I add a new instance of a custom control called `LazyImageControl` which will download the image from Azure in the background and render the image when its done.

This works just fine, but when I add a second MyBook control to the scene the images dont load for some reason, I cannot figure out why this is.

Here is the code for the `LazyImageControl`

```
public LazyImageControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContextChanged += ContextHasChanged;
    }

    private void ContextHasChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Start a thread to download the bitmap...
        _uiThreadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        new Thread(WorkerThread).Start(DataContext);
    }

    private void WorkerThread(object arg)
    {
        var imageUrlString = arg as string;
        string url = imageUrlString;

        var uriSource = new Uri(url);
        BitmapImage bi;
        if (uriSource.IsFile)
        {
            bi = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            bi.Freeze();
            _uiThreadDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new DispatcherOperationCallback(SetBitmap), bi);
        }
        else
        {
            bi = new BitmapImage();
            // Start downloading the bitmap...
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = uriSource;
            bi.UriCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default);
            bi.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            bi.DownloadFailed += DownloadFailed;
            bi.EndInit();
        }

        // Spin waiting for the bitmap to finish loading...
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }

    private void DownloadFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The bitmap has been downloaded. Freeze the BitmapImage
        // instance so we can hand it back to the UI thread.
        var bi = (BitmapImage)sender;
        bi.Freeze();

        // Hand the bitmap back to the UI thread.
        _uiThreadDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new DispatcherOperationCallback(SetBitmap), bi);

        // Exit the loop we are spinning in...
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }

    private object SetBitmap(object arg)
    {
        LazyImage.Source = (BitmapImage)arg;
        return null;
    }
```

So the issue is, doing this after the first time the WorkerThread runs fine, but I never get a callback to the `DownloadCompleted` or `DownloadFailed` methods and I have no idea why...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but maybe you should try attaching the `DownloadCompleted` and `DownloadFailed` event handlers before setting the `BitmapImage.UriSource` which should trigger the loading of the image, so it might be that it is loaded before your event handlers have been attached (Not the first time around because there the loading takes a while but then the image is cached and will be loaded immediately)

Also: From which class does `LazyImageControl` inherit so i could test it if that is not it?

Comment: I'll try that, LazyImageControl extends UserControl, its just a wrapper control for an image

Comment: Still no good, I thought that was going to be it! But no luck. I have put the images in the local drive on my PC and still no luck...

Comment: Ok, looks like my issues were larger related to the fact that I created a BitmapImage on a BG thread and tried to pass it to a UI thread, but for some reason I could not clone or freeze it, so I just ended up passing a byte[] to the UI thread and constructing an image using that...